# HTML: Required Field, need assistance

Tags: html, required

So I'm trying to make a form and I'm having trouble making it so everything is required these two no matter where I put the required field won't make them required.. Can someone explain it to me?

```
Select Your Room:
<select id="room" name="room">
  <option disabled selected>
        Choose a room
  </option>
    <option value="S308">
        S308
    </option>
    <option value="S324">
        S324
    </option>
    <option value="L2">
        L2
    </option>
    <option value="ME201">
        ME201
    </option>
    <option value="ME208">
        ME208
    </option>
</select>
<p>Machine Number:</p>
<!-- add label  here -->
<label for="machinenum">1 - 15</label>
<input id="machinenum" name="quantity" type="machinenum" min="1" max="15" value="1"><br>
```

(I'm only showing the part I don't understand. My code has `<form>`, etc.)

Comment: I don't see a required attribute on any of your code, nor do I see a `<form>` element or an `<input>` with `type` of `submit`.  You might want to check out the MDN page on [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)...

Comment: There isn't 1 single [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute in the code you posted.

Comment: I only showed the bit I dont know I can show the whole code

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below working example. Changes I made:

- put your snippet in a form
- added [required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute for select and input elements to enable HTML5 validation
- added value="" for the default option to enable
- added submit button to test the form

```html
Select Your Room:
<form>
    <select id="room" name="room" required>
      <option disabled selected value="">
            Choose a room
      </option>
        <option value="S308">
            S308
        </option>
        <option value="S324">
            S324
        </option>
        <option value="L2">
            L2
        </option>
        <option value="ME201">
            ME201
        </option>
        <option value="ME208">
            ME208
        </option>
    </select>
    <p>Machine Number:</p>
    <!-- add label  here -->
    <label for="machinenum">1 - 15</label>
    <input id="machinenum" name="quantity" type="machinenum" min="1" max="15" value="1" required><br>
    <button type="submit">
    Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Damian, you might know this http://prnt.sc/cwdwop How do I fix this error? W3 is saying The date input type is not supported in all browsers. Please be sure to test, and consider using a polyfill. CODE - <input type="date" name="reportdate" required>

Comment: @Mibby what browser are you using? `<input type="date" />` is supported in IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Chrome, but It's not just for me really

Comment: @Mibby Is that message restricting you from doing anything?  If it is just a warning, then it might not interfere with normal processes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the code that you posted is your entire 'form'.. but I will assume that it is just a section of your 'form'.

But in order to have the form elements be required, you have to add the [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute.

**Required**

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.
>
> The required attribute works with the following input types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio, and file.

Like so:

```
<form>
    Select Your Room:
    <select id="room" name="room" required>
        <option disabled selected>
            Choose a room
        </option>
        <option value="S308">
             S308
        </option>
        <option value="S324">
             S324
        </option>
        <option value="L2">
             L2
        </option>
        <option value="ME201">
             ME201
        </option>
        <option value="ME208">
             ME208
        </option>
  </select>
  <p>Machine Number:</p>
  <!-- add label  here -->
  <label for="machinenum">1 - 15</label>
  <input id="machinenum" name="quantity" type="machinenum" min="1" max="15" value="1" required><br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't work, this is what I was doing @Damian had the correct way

Comment: @Mibby okay.. that's fine. Damian also added more to your code, of which should've been in your original question.  We can only help from what you provide us.

Comment: What do you mean? My original question stated everything. I already had form and a button, etc I just didn't post that part.

Comment: @Mibby a `form` and `button` are crucial parts to getting the `required` attribute to work.. without those, then `required` is rendered useless.. so your post was considered *Minimal*.. not very *complete*

Comment: Well I had the form and button and required on other things I just thought to post the bit of my code I wasn't able to have required work on

Comment: @Mibby okay, it's no big deal.  As long as you were helped, and it is working appropriately :)